Extend `...args: Parameters<T>` to allow addition of more optional paramters at the end
I'm building a generic function which expects a function and returns a new "extended" function.
The returned function should expect the same parameters as the given base function + 1 more optional parameter at the end.
I figured out the typings to "re-use" the parameters from the given function on the returned function but I'm stuck on adding the additional optional parameter at the end.
What I have so far (the logging use case is just exemplary):
const asyncLog = async (log: string) => { /* ... */ };

function addLogging<T extends (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>>(fn: T, log: string) {
  const fnWithLogging = async (args: Parameters<T>, doLog = true) => {
    if (doLog) await asyncLog(log);
    return fn(...args);
  };
  return fnWithLogging;
}

const baseFn = async (a: number, b: string) => { /* ... */ };
const baseFnWithLogging = addLogging(baseFn, 'some log');
await baseFnWithLogging([1, '2'], false);

The shown code basically works but I don't want to pass the "base parameters" as array but want to pass all as plain parameters like baseFnWithLogging(1, '2', false).
Changing fnWithLogging(args: Parameters<T> to fnWithLogging(...args: Parameters<T> would seem to basically do the trick but I can't add the additional parameter doLog then because I get TS error 1014 A rest parameter must be last in a parameter list. then.
How can I make this work? E.g. could I do something like extend<Parameters<T>, doLog = true>?

It's telling you that arguments using spread operator can't be the first in case there are other arguments, there's still a solution by using spread operator on the type Parameters<T>, the solution is a little bit longer, because it has additional logic: Playground

What is this supposed to do in cases where the base function already has optional parameters? Or if the base function is variadic? If the arguments are false, false, false, how do I know if that's three falses to the base function, or two to the base function and one for doLog?

(see prev comment). The type system is the easy part (I'd suggest using separate type params for the args A and return type R instead of a single T that you need to evaluate Parameters<T> and ReturnType<T> on), wading through the various possible crazy runtime things with argument list lengths is the hard part. You could do it as shown in this playground link, but I'm not sure if that suffices. Do you want an answer that shows how the typings work, with caveats about runtime? Or do you want something else? How should we proceed?

@jcalz Having the restriction that the passed fns cannot have optional parameters is ok for my current use case. I went for your solution and accepted Brother58697's answer which suggests basically the same (without the separate types for params & return which I like a lot).

I guess you accepted the other answer, but not having optional parameters isn't enough. There are also variadic functions; what do you expect await addLogging(Math.max, "oops")(1, 2, 3) to produce?

Variadic fns are no important use case for me either. The fns I'm extending are rather well defined. Not completely uniform but I can easily prevent optional or indefinite params. Thanks for pointing out the caveats so carefully!

You can use the rest parameter syntax for the function then use function.length to slice the passed arguments to the functions' and the optional wrapper params.
There is a major caveat though, which is that this won't work if the passed function has any optional parameters because function.length won't count them and there's no straightforward way of getting them (except parsing the function string).
const asyncLog = async (log: string) => { /* ... */ };

function addLogging<T extends (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>>(fn: T, log: string) {
  const fnWithLogging = async (...args: [...Parameters<T>, doLog?: boolean]) => {
    const funcArgs = args.slice(0, fn.length) as Parameters<T>;
    const [doLog = false] = args.slice(fn.length) as [doLog: boolean];
    
    if (doLog) await asyncLog(log);
    return fn(...funcArgs);
  };
  return fnWithLogging;
}

const baseFn = async (a: number, b: string) => { /* ... */ };
const baseFnWithLogging = addLogging(baseFn, 'some log');
baseFnWithLogging(1, '2', false);

Playground
